# Restore Windows 10 boot

Tags: linux, windows, boot, repair

While trying to create a Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot, I messed up my booting setup. It installed grub and even that is broken. Boot blocks, boot partition, I don't know exactly what's messed up, but I wish I could clean it up. Without wiping out my Windows install.

Poking around in a recovery disk command line, I can see that my Windows 10 C: partition is still there, and seems to be in fine shape.
At this stage I'd be very content to ditch grub and Ubuntu and just have Windows booting in its own native way.  Trying...

Strategy #1: download and build a Windows install USB memory stick. Tried this. It offers two options:

1. Upgrade install. Only allowed if you have Windows already running on the machine.
2. Fresh install. Will take anything already there and move it to a directory called Windows.old or something along those lines.
   Not all right. I have apps on that Windows C: partition that I can't install again, and I really value them. I need to keep my registry!
   From years past I remember a "repair install" option on Windows install CDs. Is there any way to get that these days?

Strategy #2 (under consideration):

Use Linux dd or some such command line utility to copy my Windows partition to an external drive. Do a fresh install. Trust it to make the boot structure correct, and then copy my preserved Windows partition back over top of the new fresh one. Is this likely to work? Or is there going to be some serial number or checksum that will fail to match and cause the boot to abort?

Comment: With your Windows install USB, do [How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is *always* a good thing to make a complete disk image before any major change, such as installing a second OS, so that one can get back to the state before changes were made. Since your Windows partition appears OK, it's not too late to image the *whole drive* (even though some partitions *might*, or might not, be needed).

You can *then* try to repair booting on the existing drive, without worry about losing data.

1. Try Microsoft's [Startup Repair Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/windows-boot-issues-troubleshooting) on the USB drive you've made.

   a. On the *Install Windows* screen, select *Next > Repair your computer*.

   b. On the *Choose an option screen*, select *Troubleshoot*.

   c. On the *Advanced options* screen, select *Startup Repair*.
2. Use a third-party boot repair tool, such as [EaseUS Windows 10 Boot Repair](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/fix-uefi-boot-in-windows-10-8-7.html) or [Macrium Reflect Rescue Media](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/85198-use-macrium-reflect-rescue-media-fix-windows-boot-issues.html)